# Django-ajax submitted data and created but gives error

Tags: python, django, ajax, forms

I created a signup function captcha with the ajax method.  if the user fills up fillup captcha correctly user account is created but the user doesn't fillup captcha code incorrectly user not created. It is ok.
The problem is when user-submitted data always goes to the error block in the ajax part.
if the user fillup invalid captcha it doesn't give any error. How can I fix it?

HTML part

```
<form class="user_signup_sidebar_form" action="{% url 'account:signup-sidebar' %}"   method="post" data-mail-validation-url="{% url 'account:check_if_email_available' %}" id="customer-signup-form">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <fieldset>
                        {% bootstrap_form_errors form type="non_fields" %}
                        {% for field in signform %}
                         {% if not forloop.last %}
                            {% bootstrap_field field %}
                         {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}

                        <div class="captcha_wrapper">
                            <label for="id_captcha_1" id="id_captcha_2">{{ signform.captcha.label }}</label>
                            <div class="captcha_input">
                                {% bootstrap_field signform.captcha show_label=False %}
                                <div class="captcha_reloader">
                                    <span><i class="icon-refresh" id="js-captcha-refresh_modal"></i></span>
                                </div>

                            </div>



                        </div>


                        <style type="text/css">

                        </style>
                        {#              <input type="hidden" id="id_next" name="{{ REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME }}" value="{{ request.get_full_path }}"/>#}
                    </fieldset>

                    {% url 'page:details' slug='customer-terms-conditions' as page_details_url %}

                    <p>By clicking "Signup", you agree on aadi <a target="_blank" href="{{ page_details_url }}">Terms & Conditions</a>.</p>

                    <div class="form-group w-100 align-items-center d-flex justify-content-center m-0">

                        <button title="Signup" type="submit" class="btn btn-dark w-100 text-uppercase">Signup</button>

                    </div>


                    <a title="Seller Signup" rel="nofollow" class="link--styled pt15" href="{% url 'account:vendor-signup' %}">

                        Want to be a seller at aadibd ?

                    </a>

                    <div class="form-group social-btn-sidebar text-center m-0">
                            
                        {% with available_backends=site.settings.available_backends %}
                            <div class="form-group social-btn-sidebar m-0">
                                <span class="social-login-title">Or Signup With</span>

                                <!--Code for Google and facebook Old format

                                {% if 'facebook' in backends.backends and 'facebook' in available_backends %}
                                    <a title="Login with facebook" class="btn social-btn facebook w-100 text-align-center mb-3" href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}">
                                        {% trans 'Facebook' %}
                                    </a>
                                {% endif %}

                                {% if 'google-oauth2' in backends.backends and 'google-oauth2' in available_backends %}
                                    <a title="Login with google" class="btn social-btn google w-100 text-align-center" href="{% url 'social:begin' 'google-oauth2' %}">
                                        {% trans 'Google' %}
                                    </a>
                                {% endif %}
                                -->

                                <div class="signup-with-social sign-with-social">
                                    {% if 'facebook' in backends.backends and 'facebook' in available_backends %}
                                                    <a title="Login with facebook" class="btn social-btn sign-with-social-btn facebook text-align-center" href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}">

                                                        <i class="icofont-facebook"></i>

                                                    </a>
                                                {% endif %}


                                                {% if 'google-oauth2' in backends.backends and 'google-oauth2' in available_backends %}
                                                    <a title="Login with google" class="btn social-btn sign-with-social-btn google text-align-center" href="{% url 'social:begin' 'google-oauth2' %}">

                                                        <i class="icofont-google-plus"></i>

                                                    </a>
                                                {% endif %}

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        {% endwith %}

                    </div>

                </form>
```

ajax part: **when the user-submitted data always goes to error block in this part**

```
$(document).on('submit', '.user_signup_sidebar_form',function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        let data = $(this).serialize();
        let url = $(this).attr("action");

        $.ajax({
            url:url,
            type: "post",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            beforeSend: function () {
                console.log(this.data);
                console.log("Sending User Sign up request.............");

            },
            success:function(response){
                alert("succsesfully account created");
                $('.account_created').html("<label id=\"id_account_created_success\" class=\"text-success\"  style=\"margin: 0px;\">Account is created successfully.</label>")
            },
            error : function(xhr) {
                $('.form_error').html("<label id=\"id_confirm_password-error\" class=\"text-danger\"  style=\"margin: 0px;\">Form not create</label>")
                console.log("Form error for form client side");
            }
    });

});
```

views.py part

```
@is_user_logged_in
@find_and_assign_anonymous_cart()
def signup_sidebar(request):
    if request.region.code.upper() == settings.DEFAULT_LOCAL_COUNTRY:
        form = LocalSignupForm(request.POST or None)
    else:
        form = SignupForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        confirm_password = form.cleaned_data.get('confirm_password')
        email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        _group = Group.objects.get(name='customer')
        user = auth.authenticate(
            request=request, email=email, password=password)
        _group.user_set.add(user)

        if user:
            # Get Client IP Address
            current_user = user
            client_ip = get_client_ip(request)
            current_user.last_login_user_ip = client_ip
            current_user.last_login_user_country = get_country_by_ip(client_ip)
            current_user.save()

            if user.groups.filter(name='customer').exists():

                request.session['is_customer'] = True

                # send welcome email, with four featured products
                # featured_products = products_for_homepage()
                domain = request.site
                scheme = request.is_secure() and "https" or "http"
                domain = "{}://{}".format(scheme, domain)
                email_tpl_context = {
                    "request": request,
                    "customer_name": email,
                    "domain": domain,
                    # it will be changed to customer name (there is no name field right now!)
                    # "featured_products": featured_products[:4],
                }

                if request.region.code.upper() == settings.DEFAULT_LOCAL_COUNTRY and user.phone_number:
                    send_sms('Thank you for registering on aadi.com.bd', user.phone_number.national_number)

                send_customer_signup_welcome_email(email_tpl_context, email)
                auth.login(request, user)
                if request.region.code.upper() == settings.DEFAULT_LOCAL_COUNTRY:
                    campaign = PopupCampaignSettings.objects.filter(is_local=True).public().first()

                else:

                    campaign = PopupCampaignSettings.objects.filter(is_global=True).public().first()

                if campaign:
                    signup_user_send_email_with_coupon(request, user, user.email, None)
                    messages.success(request,
                                     "Your account has been successfully created and an email is sent to {} with coupon".format(
                                         user.email))
                else:
                    messages.success(request, "Your account has been successfully created")
                redirect_url = request.POST.get('next', settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)
                return redirect(redirect_url)
            else:
                messages.warning(request, _('You can not sign up here'))
                user.delete()
                redirect_url = request.POST.get('next', settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)
                return redirect(redirect_url)
        else:
            print("form.errors", form.errors)

    ctx = {'form': form}

    return TemplateResponse(request, 'account/signup.html', ctx)
```

Also, I want to when user successfully created a profile then redirect to the dashboard page. is sit possible is ajax part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just remove this line from ajax

```
 dataType: 'json',
```